# is there a way to filter array based on flag inside an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I am trying to do filter an array based on flag `isSome: true`. I want to filter when that flag is not present in that array

```js
var value = [
      { "somevalues": {},
        "moreDetails": {
          "isSome": "true"
        }
      },
      { "somevalues": {},
        "moreDetails": {}
      },
      { "somevalues": {},
        "moreDetails": {}
      },
    ]
const valuewithisSome = value.filter(o => o.moreDetails &&  o.moreDetails.isSome);
const valuewithoutisSome = value.filter(o => o.moreDetails &&  !o.moreDetails.isSome);
console.log(valuewithisSome);
console.log(valuewithoutisSome);
```

`valuewithisSome` is working as expected and returning array with `isSome: true`.

`valuewithoutisSome` is not working as expected as i don't want to pass isSome false in morevalues array, is there a way to filter without even passing that flag?

Comment: How exactly is the "without" version not working? As written it should be fine.

Comment: "Run code snippet" shows that it actually works. This is probably not your real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "without" code you already have should work:

```
const valuewithoutisSome = value.filter(o => o.moreDetails &&  !o.moreDetails.isSome);
```

The expression `o.moreDetails.isSome` will evaluate to `undefined` if the "isSome" property is missing or explicitly false-y, so `!o.moreDetails.isSome` will be `true` in that case.

Now while that will work, if you want to explicitly test for the property being false *only* when it's actually present, you can do this:

```
const valuewithoutisSome = value.filter(o => 
  o.moreDetails &&
  (!("isSome" in o.moreDetails) || !o.moreDetails.isSome)
);
```

That will only return `false` (and filter out the array entry) when the "isSome" property is present. If it's not, or if it's present and `true`, then the entry will be in the filtered result.

Comment: Thank you much, thats a great help, but I was getting null in the console for valuewithoutisSome. Is there a way we can use .some() in that filter()?

Comment: Well `.filter()` will never return `null`; are you sure your test code is really the same as what you posted? The code exactly as written in your question does not show `null` for `valuewithoutisSome`.

Comment: It was working in the codesnippet here, when I try to do the same thing in my visual studio code, I am seeing an empty array for valuewithoutisSome

Comment: Look carefully at your actual code, in particular for differences. There could be something that looks harmless but that is in fact a critical change.

Comment: Thanks,my mock data actually doesn't have moreDetails in other arrays except the first one. I think thats what is making a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your isSome property type is string. Remove double quetos from true.

{ "somevalues": {},
        "moreDetails": {
          "isSome": true
        }
      },

Comment: This is a good suggestion, though the string `"true"` does work. However `isSome: "false"` would *also* be `true` (which is why it's a good suggestion) :)

Comment: I wanted it as boolean, I dont have double quotes for true. I somehow wrongly inserted in this mockdata, my apologies.